# advantage of having date column instead of text

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering whether defining a `DATE` datatype is more performant for a particular query, this is the statement I am using:

```
 SELECT 
    to_char(release_date,'YYYY-MM') as my_date,
    school_department,
    COUNT(*) as total
  GROUP BY school_department,my_date;
```

When inserting values for `my_date` I can have the option to insert the same day for the groups `school_department,my_date` , this will allow me to insert `my_date` as `DATE` datatype and have the same `count(*)` result. Now if i insert as `TEXT` and only define `'YYYY-MM'` it will also work. However I'm not sure whether the performance is better by defining `DATE` and then converting to `char` for the final desired result, or ingesting the data directly as `TEXT` and grouping by the text column.

So in summary I can have the following options:

1. INSERT as TEXT 'YYYY-MM' and group by just like that, don't convert to `char` in the select satement
2. INSERT as DATE and add same day for my groups and then converto to `char` in the select statement.

Comment: Choosing the appropriate data type has less to do with performance and more with constraining the allowed values. A `text` column would permit storing `'agrzfls'`, which you want to prevent.

Comment: Is that the only query that will ever use that column, or is it used in other contexts too?

Comment: is that really the query you will be using,  just like that with no where clause?

Comment: yes, most probably it is... but not sure maybe in the future other queries too..

Answer (score 2):

Using a date over a text column is definitely preferred, and would offer the following advantages:

- If you were to add a `WHERE` restriction on `my_date`, such a restriction might be able to use an index on that column (sargable)
- Internally, `my_date` would be stored as binary which would probably be more efficient than storing the date as text
- If you did have to do comparisons on `my_date`, you could use `interval` syntax or otherwise take advantage of any date function which Postgres offers.  Using a text date would mean not being able to use such date functions without first casting or converting.

Comment: You could also mention that it would help the optimiser when planning the query - a `DATE` field could be restricted to, say, certain years and even if there is no `CHECK` constraint, there are still only certain values that the query can potentially utilise. This would be very difficult with a `TEXT` field as a `DATE` - it could possibly be done with some ridiculously complex regex, but why go to the trouble of re-implementing something the database will do for you anyway using a `DATE` field? And complex regexes are not very efficient.

Comment: Also, no possibility of using the nifty `DATERANGE` or `DATEMULTIRANGE` types which can be very useful at times!

Comment: complex regex not needed for more than 7970 years, until then string comparison will work `date between '2017-00' and '2021-99'`  etc...